# From a string to a cycle in PHP

Tags: php, cycle

I have ta string, pulled from the db, where each value is separeted by '-', something like this: a-b-c.
In my db I also have a field telling me how many values I have, in this case 3.
I would need to create a textfiled for each value of the string, so I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
$numberOfValues=db=>n;
$string=bb=>string;
$singleValue = explode("-", $string);
for($i=0;$i<$numberOfValues;$i++): {
echo ('input type="text" value="'.$singleValue[$i].'">');
}
```

My question is basically: is this an efficient way of doing what I'm looking for? Or perhaps there's a "better" way?
Thank's!

Comment: You could probably do it without `$numberOfValues`, because you already know that by `$string`. When you explode, just do `foreach`.

Comment: this is probably more suited for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), flagged as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$values = explode('-', $string);

foreach ($values as $value) {
    printf('<input type="text" value="%s">', htmlspecialchars($value));
}
```

Comment: Do you think I could apply this also if I have multiple value to insert in the cycle?  (I actually have three of them, so e.g. $values2 and $values3.

Comment: `array_merge` them all into one array which you can then loop over...?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to mentioned things about foreach and valid input tag,

- You should not mix HTML with PHP logic in the way you've done. Have HTML in separate templates, preferrably.
- Make sure you always have HTML escapes happening on the values you push within HTML unless explicitly meant otherwise, so that characters `"`, `'`, `<`, `>` get escaped properly and you don't leave XSS holes around.

---

On XSS, example from your code:

```
echo ('input type="text" value="'.$singleValue[$i].'">');
```

Now, if we assume a user can affect the contents of `$singleValue[$i]`, they can push there contents like `"><script src="http://malicioussite.com/hacking.js"></script><span id="`

which would make the resulting HTML on the page

```
input type="text" value=""><script src="http://malicioussite.com/hacking.js"></script><span id="">
```

This would force end user browser to execute "hacking.js" file, which can for example steal your session information and submit it to any domain. You protect against these kind of threats the easiest by escaping some known, dangerous characters, which is what [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) function is for.

- [Wikipedia article on XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not an expert, what you mean with XSS holes?

Comment: Mmm really good to know! I'll review all my code! So if I use htmlspecialchars() I should be fine in respect to that issue, right?

Comment: You should be fine in respect to this specific issue with HTML, yes. There are similar escaping topics regarding the database, executing shell commands, outputting headers such as cookies etc. Note also that you should give ENT_QUOTES param to htmlspecialchars() so it will quote `'` too. It also has a character set parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok. But open and close the input tag :)

```
echo ('<input type="text" value="'.$singleValue[$i].'"/>');
```